# difference between creating an iphone app & mac os app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I am an iphone/ipad apps developer.Now I also want to create mac apps.
I wanted to know that how should I start learning mac app development.
I started by creating the Currency converter app in the apple docs.But that is quite simple.
I wanted to explore about the different controls for mac app.
Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of your basic Obj-C/Cocoa knowledge (Foundation.framework-related stuff) will directly translate. The primary difference is UIKit vs. AppKit for the UI. The overall controller-layer architecture also has some differences (view-controller specific stuff).

To explore the controls, open Interface Builder, create a plain Cocoa Application xib and start exploring the controls by dragging them into a window. Use the API reference as your guide.

Happy coding.

Comment: I would also suggest researching bindings. If you want to create document based applications, you should research the document architecture.